# Kotlin: problem with var x= temp.text.toString().toInt()

Tags: android, kotlin

Just started with Kotlin, and when I write my code, text is an unresolved reference. I copied the code from the solution the teacher gave me and I don't really understand that line or why `.text` is a problem

Here is the code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.Button

import android.widget.Toast

import android.widget.TextView

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var result: TextView
    lateinit var temp: Toast
    lateinit var CToF: Button
    lateinit var FToC: Button


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        FToC.setOnClickListener{
            var x= temp.text.toString().toInt()
            x= (x-32)* 5/9
            result.text= "result is $x"
        }
        CToF.setOnClickListener{
            var x = temp.text.toString().toInt()
            x= (x* 9/5)+32
            result.text= "result is $x"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is correctly referenced, but `import.kotlinx` is not used and the line I wrote before is a problem because of `.text`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With that, some user could help you better.

Comment: This app is asking for trouble b/c you use integer division for your temperature conversion.  If you ever get this working your next question will be "why am I not getting the correct conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit?"  Replace 9/5 with 1.8 and you'll do much better.  Likewise for 5/9 - it's equal to zero according to integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 lateinit var temp: Toast
```

you've declared temp as a Toast, and there's no getter for text on a toast, just a set.

---

I don't know why you're using `lateinit var` for components if you're using synthetic imports

---

If you *don't* use synthetic imports and keep using lateinit values, your app will just crash too. Lots of stuff you need to relook

Comment: At first, when i did'nt add lateinit var to the code it just didn't work because it didn't recognize the elements from the xml, but now that i've rewritten it entirely without the lateninit, it works! so thank you